# close/collapse an accordion menu when click outside of menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I have a rather complex accordion menu that I need to do two things..
When the user clicks off of the menu I want it to:
1. close/collapse all tabs 
AND 
2. close/collapse all submenu items.

I don't know any programming but html and css, so I'm having an enormous amount of trouble getting this accordion menu to behave.

I can get it to collapse when I click on other tabs, but I can't get the sucker to close up when I click outside of the menu (which I want it to do too).

I'm also brand new here, I haven't a clue how to go about this.

I have an accordion with a header/button, subITEMS, and a few have a subMENU too.

Here is an example of what I've got:

```
        <!-- Accordion menu START -->
        <div id="accordion" class="panel-group" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="list-group panel">

            <!-- Item 1 -->
            <a href="#morocco" role="button"  class="panel-heading list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Morocco <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="morocco">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a class="list-group-item strong" href="#">Homepage</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a class="list-group-item strong" href="="#">">Casablanca</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- END Item 1  -->

            <!-- Item 2  basically the same as item 1  -->

            <!-- Item 3   -->
            <a href="#france" role="button" class="panel-heading list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">France <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i></a>

            <div class="collapse" id="france">
              <!-- Alsace -->
              <a class="list-group-item" href="="#"">Alsace</a>

              <!-- burgundy -->
              <a href="#burgundy" role="button" class="panel-heading list-group-item strong" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#burgundy">Burgundy <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></a>

              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu list-group-submenu-1" id="burgundy">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="="#"" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#burgundySubMenu">Homepage</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a class="list-group-item strong" href="#" target="_self">Dijon</a>
                      </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Item 3 -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Accordion END -->
```

I've been using this script to close the submenu

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#france').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
      console.log('triggered');
      $('#burgundy').collapse('hide');
    });
  });
```

but I need the whole accordion menu to close/collapse when the user isn't using the menu anymore... I hate menus that stay open when not in use.

Any help would be sooooooo appreciated... I'm at my wits end!

And I apologize for my sloppy code... I can do css and html, I didn't say I was good at it! :)

I forgot to mention... this code ALMOST worked...

```
<script>
$("html").click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('#accordion, #burgundy').length === 0) {
          jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
});

</script>
```

it'd close the accordion menu, but it'd leave the tabs open when clicking around INSIDE the menu. I need it to close the tabs when clicking another tab AND close whole menu when click outside of menu.

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: This was so long ago! :) 
I think so. Otherwise I just did something else... I can't remember anymore.
But, THANK YOU for responding!!!